# jQuery Validation not showing message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to using jQuery Validation and have not been able to get it to work. I am just trying to have a message pop out saying missing first name. Is there anything missing in this script?

```
 <!-- Validate -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
        firstname_1: { required:true },
        //same for your other fields
    }, {
    messages: {
        firstname_1: "Missing first name",
    }
});

<cfform name="form" id="form" method="post">

    <cfoutput><input type="text" name="firstname_#Add#" id="firstname_#Add#" placeholder="First"  validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" required="yes" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s first name." value="#session.checkout.info["firstname_" & Add]#"></cfoutput>
```

Comment: You do not seem to have a form wrapper element around your inputs, also the input type isn't matching the code in the validator script.

Comment: There's no `<form id="form">`

Comment: Yes `<form id="form"> ..inputs..   </form>`

Comment: cfform isn't a html form, I hardly doubt if jQuery gets this?

Comment: @Mouser He's using ColdFusion, I assume it will convert that to an HTML form.

Comment: You have no `rules:` option in your `validate()` argument.

Comment: @Barmar That will probably be right :-)

Comment: I've rolled back the last revision because you edited the problem out of your code.  Please do not fix the code in the OP; otherwise, the solutions posted below make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the arguments to `.validate()` wrong. It just takes a single options argument, and the validation rules go in that argument:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname_1: {
            required: true
        },
        // Same for other fields
    },
    messages: {
        firstname_1: "Missing first name",
        // Repeat for other fields
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the `errorClass` option to specify a class that should be put on inputs that have an error, and set the CSS for that class to have red background.

Comment: The class defaults to `error`, so you can just add CSS for `input.error { background-color: red; }`.

Comment: Actually, if you just want a red box, use `border-color`. I just tried this on one of my forms and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69926/discussion-between-kte-and-barmar).

Comment: @KTE, you can also review the [SO Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for all the links and basic info, not to mention looking at the code in [the thousands of other SO questions tagged with jQuery Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes).